# How to send messages from thread to thread using winapi32 functions in c#?

Tags: c#, multithreading, winapi

I've got a task where I need to send a message to a thread from another thread.
I have a class for this task, here it is:

```
public class MyThread
{
    public Thread Thrd { get; set; }
    public MyThread Next { get; set; }


    public MyThread()
    {
        Thrd = new Thread(Work);
    }

    public void Start()
    {
        Thrd.Start();
    }

    private void Work()
    {
        while (true)
        {
            if (//Has message to receive)
            {
                //Get message and do work
                //Send message to the Next.Thrd
            }
        }
    }
    
}
```

As a message I just need to send an integer. I found functions like PostThreadMessageA and GetMessageA that can be useful for me, is this right? Also, these require a handle to a thread, how can I get it? Finally, is there a function that does check if there's a message to receive for this thread (that I could put instead of "//Has message to receive")?

Comment: PostMessage() requires a window (not a thread), a message loop and a thread-safe queue (provided by the OS).  Infrastructure that you don't have or need.  It is but one solution to the producer-consumer problem, the standard one in .NET is [BlockingCollection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.concurrent.blockingcollection-1?view=net-5.0).

Comment: Yes, I saw a solution using ConcurrentQueue, but I need to use these api functions. I probably meant PostThreadMessageA instead of PostMessage

Comment: Why do you need to use these functions? Very likely your mistaken in that belief.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I understand that it's easy to make mistakes with these functions, but it's a part of my task to use them

Comment: Do you want to solve a problem, or do you just want to call these functions?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan both! Now I got it already and posted the answer here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> these require a handle to a thread, how can I get it?

You could use [`GetCurrentThreadId`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-getcurrentthreadid) to get the threadid after the thread starts.

> is there a function that does check if there's a message to receive
> for this thread?

Yes, [`GetMessage`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getmessage)/[`PeekMessage`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-peekmessagea)(`GetMessage` will wait for the message to arrive, but `PeekMessage` does not wait for a message to be posted before returning.)

The following is the win32 solution. Two threads thread1, thread2 (thread1.Next = thread2) are created in the main thread. The main thread sends data to thread1, and then thread1 receives the message and sends its data to thread2:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApp
{
    public class MyThread
    {
        
        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
        public struct POINT
        {
            public int x;
            public int y;
        }
        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
        public struct MSG
        {
            public IntPtr hwnd;
            public int message;
            public UIntPtr wParam;
            public IntPtr lParam;
            public int time;
            public POINT pt;
            public int lPrivate;
        }
        [DllImport("Kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
        public static extern int GetCurrentThreadId();
        
        [DllImport("User32.dll",SetLastError = true,CharSet =CharSet.Auto)]
        public static extern bool PostThreadMessage(int idThread, uint Msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);

        [DllImport("User32.dll", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
        public static extern bool GetMessage(out MSG Msg, IntPtr hWnd, uint wMsgFilterMin, uint wMsgFilterMax);
        [DllImport("User32.dll", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
        public static extern bool PeekMessage(out MSG Msg, IntPtr hWnd, uint wMsgFilterMin, uint wMsgFilterMax,uint wRemoveMsg);
        public static uint WM_USER = 0x0400;
        public Thread Thrd { get; set; }
        public MyThread Next { get; set; }
        public int ThreadId { get; set; }
        public int data { get; set; }
        public MyThread()
        {
            Thrd = new Thread(Work);
            ThreadId = -1;
        }

        public void Start()
        {
            Thrd.Start();
        }
        public static bool SendTo(int data, MyThread target_thread)
        {
            IntPtr lparam = new IntPtr(data);
            return PostThreadMessage(target_thread.ThreadId, WM_USER, IntPtr.Zero, lparam);
        }
        private void Work()
        {
            ThreadId = GetCurrentThreadId();
            data = ThreadId;
            while (true)
            {
                MSG msg = new MSG();
                IntPtr hwnd = new IntPtr(-1);
                if (GetMessage(out msg, IntPtr.Zero, 0, 0))
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("received : " + msg.lParam.ToInt32());
                    if (Next != null)
                        SendTo(data, Next);
                }
            }
        }

    }
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            MyThread thread1 = new MyThread();
            MyThread thread2 = new MyThread();
            thread1.Next = thread2;
            thread1.Start();
            thread2.Start();

            //To Do
            //To Ensure that the thread has been started, and the thread ID has been obtained through GetCurrentThreadId
            Thread.Sleep(1000); 

            MyThread.SendTo(50, thread1);

            //To Do
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

To get what I wanted I used these functions:

```
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
    private static extern bool PeekMessage(
        out InternalMessage lpInternalMessage,
        IntPtr hWnd,
        uint wMsgFilterMin,
        uint wMsgFilterMax,
        uint wRemoveMsg
    );

    [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
    private static extern bool PostThreadMessage(
        uint threadId,
        uint msg,
        UIntPtr wParam,
        IntPtr lParam
        );

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
    public static extern uint GetCurrentThreadId();
```

and also I needed to define such a structure:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct InternalMessage
{
    public IntPtr hwnd;
    public uint message;
    public UIntPtr wParam;
    public IntPtr lParam;
    public int time;
    public Point pt;
    public int lPrivate;
}
```